# Magento 2. Where is the catalog search ES index created?

Tags: search, elasticsearch

Magento creates an index in ES for various search features.
I'm interested where in the code is index created/updated/repopulated?

I'm thinking some cron or indexer. I've looked in module-catalog-search and module-catalog-advanced-search but can't seem to find the code that actually builds and sends the request to ES.

**EDIT:** \Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Index\Builder::build() this what I have atm.

Answer (score 0):

```
\Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\Adapter\Elasticsearch::prepareIndex()
```

The index general structure is defined here

```
$this->client->createIndex($indexName, ['settings' => $settings]);
```

Attribute information is added here

```
$this->client->addFieldsMapping(
            $allAttributeTypes,
            $indexName,
            $this->clientConfig->getEntityType()
        );
```